# Showing that the expectation of a function of $Bin(n,p)$ is increasing and concave in $p$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Consider the function
\begin{align}
f(p) = p\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\frac{1}{k+1}, \quad 0\leq p\leq 1.
\end{align}
Is there a smart way to show that $f(p)$ is increasing and concave in $p$? This can be confirmed by plotting the function.

The function can of course be written as
\begin{align}
f(p) = p \mathbb{E}\big[\frac{1}{X+1}\big],
\end{align}
where $X$ is a $Bin(n,p)$ random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306901/find-the-expected-value-of-frac1x1-where-x-is-binomial), we know that
\begin{align}
f(p)= \frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{n+1}.
\end{align}
From this form, it is easy to compute $f'(p)$ and $f''(p)$, whereupon you will see that $f'(p)>0$ and $f''(p)<0$ for all $p\in (0,1)$.